# First CAST then concatenate (||) in Firebird

Tags: sql, casting, concatenation, firebird

How does one cast and then join elements together in Firebird?

```sql
SELECT 
ARTICLE_NAME ||','||CAST 
FROM 
(select cast(QUANTITY as varchar(50)) from PREORDER_ITEM)
```

I also tried

```sql
with DATA as ( select cast(QUANTITY as varchar(50) ) from PREORDER_ITEM )
 SELECT 
    ARTICLE_NAME ||','||QUANTITY
FROM 
    DATA
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  When you say, "doesn't work" — what does that mean?  What errors do you see, and what do you think they're trying to tell you?

Comment: why would you even want to typecast `QUANTITY` ? Just let it be auto-casted,  `SELECT 
ARTICLE_NAME || ', ' || QUANTITY FROM ...`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your query:

1. When you do `select cast(QUANTITY as varchar(50) ) from PREORDER_ITEM` you have only one (1) column in the derived table. In other words, there is no `ARTICLE_NAME` in either query.
2. For a select expression of a derived table or common table expression, all columns must have an explicit column name. So, for an expression you need to specify an explicit alias using (`AS <alias>`). In other words, there is no column `CAST` in your first query, and no column `QUANTITY` in the second.
3. `CAST` is a reserved word, so when used as a column name like in your first query, it must be delimited by double quotes.

So, use:

```sql
select article_name || quantity
from (
  select article_name, cast(quantity as varchar(50)) as quantity
  from preorder_item
)
```

or

```sql
with data as (
  select article_name, cast(quantity as varchar(50)) as quantity
  from preorder_item
)
select article_name || quantity
from data
```

As an aside, you don't need to explicitly cast. When concatenating values, Firebird will automatically coerce to a string value, so you can also use:

```sql
select article_name || quantity 
from preorder_item
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the topic 2. usage of alias    `   with data as (
  select article_name || quantity
  from preorder_item
)
select *
from data           `

Comment: @MichaelPietzsch When you use a derived table, all columns must have a name, if you have only an expression, the column doesn't have a name (in a top-level query, a name will be generated, but not in derived tables and sub-queries). So you need to specify a name by using an alias using `<expression> [AS] <alias>` (`AS` is optional, but for readability it is better to always use it).

Comment: @MichaelPietzsch If my answer helped you solve the problem, then please accept it by clicking the checkmark.